# c++ friend class keyword within class definition

Tags: c++, class

I was just wondering what is happening with the following code:

```cpp
class SomeClass {

public:
    void someMethod();
private:
    bool _someValue;
}

class SomeOtherClass {

friend class SomeClass;

public:
    void someOtherMethod();

private:
    bool _someOtherValue;

}
```

I've been having a bit of a read of the following page in the 'Friend classes' and it seems that the friend class has access to the defining class?
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

If that is the case, what is the difference between using `friend class SomeClass` and just inheriting the classes such as `class SomeOtherClass : SomeClass { }`??

Comment: See [`friend` declaration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend). `friend`ship has *nothing* to do with inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between "having access to private members" and "being <s>composed of</s> a" (Edit: actually composition is another thing).

```
#include <iostream>    

class B;

class A {
  friend class B;
private:
  int x;
};

class B {
  static void print(const A& a) {
    // A::x is private, but B is a friend of A, so it's fine
    std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  B::print(a);
  return 0;
}
```

This is legal. `A::x` is private, but it can be used by `B`'s methods as `A` declares that `B` is a friend class and can access its private/protected members. However, `B` isn't an `A`, in particular, `B` is an empty class (that's why you have to pass an `A` to print).

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
  int x;
};

class B : public A {
  void print() {
    // error A::x is private!
    std::cout << A::x << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.print();
  return 0;
}
```

This is illegal. `B` inherits from `A` but it doesn't grant him any access to its private members, even if it actually contains them. `B` isn't empty anymore and actually contains an instance of `A` (hence of `A::x` although it cannot access it)

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
protected:
  int x;
};

class B : public A {
  void print() {
    // A::x is protected, but B inherits from A, so it's fine
    std::cout << A::x << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  B b;
  b.print();
  A a;
  // error a::x is protected and can only be accessed from A or from any class which inherits from A
  // std::cout << a.x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This is legal. `B` has access to the protected member `A::x` as it inherits from `A`, `B` is also an `A` and is actually non-empty.

Answer (score 2):

`Inherit` means too many things, it's irrelevant with `friend` at all.

Just focused on the access right, the friend class can access the public/protected/private members of the defining class, while the derived class only can access the public/protected members of the base class.

Answer (score 2):

By inheriting derived class will include memory layout of the base class. If base has a integer it means your derive class will have it too.

```
class A 
{
    int a1;
};

class B : public A 
{
    int b1 ;
};
```

B b ; sizeof(b) is 8 bytes now since it also includes A's variables.

Friend classes do not have anything to do with base classes memory layout they won't have what base class have. Friend declarations will only help you with access control. That means if class B has a pointer of class A:

```
class B : public A 
{
    int b1 ;
    A *a;

    void foo()
    {
       std::cout << a->a1; --> possible because B is a friend of A 
    }
}
```

Avoid friend decleration if you can because it is good to hide the information.

Answer (score 2):

Friendship is a hack. It allows class A to give objects of class B *some* of the sort of access that it would do if it inherited from class A. However, the two features are not the same.

Just one difference is that an inheriting class can access only `public` and `protected` members of the base, whereas a friended class has full access to everything, including `private` members.

Friendship does not form an inheritance heirarchy, so no new conversions are made possible. Objects of type `B` do not automatically *have* members from a sub-object of type `A`; it's just that they're able to access members in some arbitrary object of type `A` if they can see one somewhere.

- **`friend` is like giving someone all your bank details**
- **inheritance is like setting up a joint account**